# Rewrite URLs in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

How can I rewrite the following urls in CodeIgniter

```
localhost/users/show_profile/john
```

to

```
localhost/john
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can achieve dynamic URL using [CodeIgniter Routes](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html).

Assuming 
`localhost/users/show_profile/john`

We're looking at:

```
localhost/controller/method/variable
```

we can use the following route:

```
$route['([a-zA-z_]+)'] = "users/show_profile/$1";
```

You can access the variable by calling `$this->uri->segment(1);` inside show_profile() function.

**IMPORTANT:** keep the `$route['([a-zA-z_]+)']` at the end of the routes.php file, to make sure it's not overriding any other routes.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to do it for a defined set of URLs, update /config/routes.php

If you need it to be dynamic then you should extend the CodeIgniter Router Library.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html (look for **Extending Native Libraries**)

Answer (score 0):

In `config/routes.php` add `$route['(:any)'] = "users/show_profile/$1";`

More info on routes [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)

Comment: I wouldn't use (:any), because it's greedy. I would look at regex routes instead.