# How can I remove index.php from URL?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CodeIgniter - How to hide index.php from the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770451/codeigniter-how-to-hide-index-php-from-the-url)

How can I remove `index.php` from the URL using `.htaccess` so when user types in, for example:

> http://localhost/index.php/welcome

it will become :

> http://localhost/welcome

Currently
With my current `.htaccess`, both of the urls above will be able to access the controller `welcome`, but I would like only 1 valid url for the controller.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|admin_assets|img|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1
```

Answer (score 1):

in your config.php file search for this line:

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php";
```

edit it like this:

```
$config['index_page'] = ""; //remove index.php from there
```

and add this in your htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

Options -Indexes

DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on



RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|sitemap\.xml)

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this also does not works, Zekiel want to redirect: `http://localhost/index.php/welcome` to `http://localhost/welcome` he say that url rewrites works he just need to redirect

Answer (score 0):

There are about 50000 questions handling this as well as a big wiki post about it

http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite/

[ModRewrite not working for codeigniter site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696469/modrewrite-not-working-for-codeigniter-site)

[Rewrite URLs in CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219762/rewrite-urls-in-codeigniter)

[CodeIgniter - How to hide index.php from the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770451/codeigniter-how-to-hide-index-php-from-the-url)

... those should help

Comment: Nope, these dont tell me how to actually remove the index.php from the URL when user typing in index.php/welcome. basically, all the articles and threads were about making http://localhost/welcome a valid request.

Answer (score 0):

Simple and fast solution :

> Just create a `.htaccess` file with the below code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(admin_assets|img|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

And then place it to the root of your `CI` application near `index.php`.

This modified `.htaccess` file satisfy your requirements, (ie `you don't want the user to be able to access the same page with 2 different urls's`)

> Q. What will it do?
>   A. It will guide all request to your application to index.php including those url which contains `index.php` except(admin_assets,img,css,js folder and your robots.txt, favicon.ico files) obviously on apache.

CodeIgniter's own documentation is very good, [URL's in CI](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html)